# Program shows random symbols instead of text

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote this program in Assembly. I am using MALM compiler for 8086 processor. This program is intended to show 3 messages and take 3 values. I am just beginnier and have problem to identify the mistake that was done.

```
dane1 segment
a   db 30,0
    db 31 dup(?)
    db '$'
d   db ?
    db'$'
b   db 30,0
    db 31 dup(?)
    db '$'
tx1 db "Enter the first number (max 30 characters) :",10,13,"$"
    db ?
tx2 db "Enter the symbol *,+,-,/: ",10,13,"$"
    db ?
tx3 db "Enter the second number (max 30 characters): ",10,13,"$"
    db ?
nline db 10,13,"$"
    db ?
dane1 ends
code1 segment
start1:
    mov sp,offset wstosu    ;stack initzialization
    mov ax,seg wstosu
    mov ss,ax

    ;showing the first message
    mov dx, offset tx1
    mov ax, seg tx1
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    ;getting input
    mov ax, seg dane1
    mov ds,ax
    mov dx,offset a
    mov ah,0AH

    ;loading input to a
    mov bh,0 
    mov bl,byte ptr ds:[a+1]
    add bx,offset a+2
    mov byte ptr ds:[bx],'$'
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset nline
    mov ax, seg nline
    mov ds,ax
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    ;showing the second message
    mov dx, offset tx2
    mov ax, seg tx2
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    ;getting input
    mov ax, seg dane1
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx, offset d
    mov ah, 0AH

    ;loading input to d
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, byte ptr ds:[d+1]
    add bx, offset d+2
    mov byte ptr ds:[bx],'$'
    int 21h

    ;new line
    mov dx, offset nline
    mov ax, seg nline
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    ;showing third message
    mov dx, offset tx3
    mov ax, seg tx3
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h


code1 ends
stos1 segment stack
    dw 200 dup(?)
wstosu  dw ?
stos1 ends
end start1
```

EDIT1:
I change the code as @Micheal suggested but still getting the random symbol when I try to show tx2.

EDIT2:
I managed somehow to show messages instead of random symbols, but now program do not wait for second input. I will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that registers still hold values that have since been changed:

```
mov ax,seg dane1        
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset tx1
mov ah, 09h   <-- Here you're altering the high 8 bits of ax
int 21h       <-- int 21h / function 9h will destroy al

mov ds,ax     <-- Here you assume that ax still holds seg dane1, which it doesn't
```

There may be other problems in your code, this was just the most obvious one.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested, but still getting random symbols.   Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: I changed the code, but now program do not wait for input. I will be glad for any help.